# posting ajax data with jquery function error

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i have a jquery datatable which get loaded with excel sheet data and i needed to pass to controller. i used

```
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: "Bfrtip",
          //  "processing": true,
            //"serverSide": true,

            "ajax": {
                "url": 'Url to controller',
                "contentType": "application/json",

                "dataSrc": "",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function(d){
                    d.form = $("#frm").serializeArray();
                }
            }
         }

    $("frm").on("submit", function () {
    var data = table.$("input, select,textarea").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: " /Controller/Create",
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            $.redirect(response.url, { 'data': JSON.stringify(response.data) }, "POST");

        }
    });


    return false;
});
```

to pass data on submit button click.

my controller action i tried many ways to retrieve data but all coming null.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create( FormCollection frm, [System.Web.Http.FromBody]object value,string formdata, string data)
    {
    }
```

fiddler says no responebody and json results are empty.

can somebody please point me out where i have went wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: in your $("frm").on("submit", function ()  `$("frm")` doesn't look like a valid selector

Answer (score 0):

Update your AJAX code with below.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: " /Controller/Create",
        data:"{'data':data}",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            $.redirect(response.url, { 'data': JSON.stringify(response.data) }, "POST");

        }
    });
```

The name and param of the controller and the AJAX  call should match. Use only data param.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(string data)
    {
    }
```